# Test that Python code only uses ABC methods

Tags: python-2.7, abstract-base-class

Let's say I have a function that is documented to take a [`collections.Sequence` ABC](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Sequence). How do I test the code within this function against the ABC interface? Can I write a unit test (or tests) confirming that my code only calls methods defined by this ABC and not, say, a method defined by `list` or some other concrete implementation of `collections.Sequence`? Or is there some other tool or method to verify this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply test the function by passing an instance of a class that only implements those methods. If you need to, you can subclass a built-in type such as `list` and override its [__getattribute__](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method, like this:

```
class TestSequence(list):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name not in collections.Sequence.__abstractmethods__:
            assert(False) # or however you'd like the test to fail
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
```

Comment: "an instance of a class that only implements those methods" — this is the core of what I'm asking, I think: is there an easier way to obtain such a thing? Your method works, but duplicates information that is already in the ABC. Thus, there's a risk of getting out of sync, making another mistake, etc. (Also, if someone were to do this, they might be better off using a mock object or similar... depending on the test.)

Comment: Would using `if name not in Sequence.__abstractmethods__` solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the ABC directly yourself, with methods as trivial or complex as needed by the code:

```
import collections

class TestSequence(collections.Sequence):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __len__(self):
        return 3

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return index
```

If you make a mistake and omit abstract method implementations, your code will produce an error:

```
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class TestSequence with abstract methods __getitem__
```

If your code under test calls a method not defined by the ABC, you will see the usual no attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'TestSequence' object has no attribute 'pop'
```